# Delete SQL server records without reindex

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I guess there must be an auto reindex every time a delete takes place. If there are too many deletes for many tables resulting in many records deleted, reindexing will also be time consuming.

Is there any way way to avoid reindexing when deleting records (for it done later in a batch mode)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no auto-reindex after deletes (on any of the mainstream RDBMS's).

Statistics are updated (provided they are not turned off).

Re-indexing is typically a long operation, carried out during maintenance window.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to supress the statistics (turn off) so that time is saved there too?

Comment: You can turn off auto updating of statistics, but it will most likely be detrimental to performance.